# openDatabase error: Cannot convert null value to object

Tags: android, react-native, sqlite, react-native-sqlite-storage, opendatabase

I'm using [react-native-sqlite-storage](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage), wanted to use  [JSON Functions And Operators](https://www.sqlite.org/json1.html) and after reading the issues I found that I need to use the Android native SQLite [#480](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/issues/480). Then I changed the react-native.config.js in order to use SQLite bundled with the library. Make some adjustments to run the test example given [in the docs](https://github.com/andpor/react-native-sqlite-storage/blob/master/test/index.android.json1.js) but get an error at opening the database:

```
 OPEN database: Test.db
 LOG  SQLite.open({"name":"Test.db","dblocation":"nosync"})
 ERROR  TypeError: Cannot convert null value to object, js engine: hermes
```

I'm using Windows and the RN Android emulator (default script: npm run android) with these package's versions:

```
"dependencies": {
    "deprecated-react-native-listview": "^0.0.8",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.3",
    "react-native-sqlite-storage": "^6.0.1"
  },
```

I'll like to upload the stack trace but I don't know how to extract it from the device. A few steps from the stack outputed in the device, all of them related to sqlite.core.js file:

```
1 --- plugin.exec
2 --- SQLitePlugin.prototype.open
3 --- SQLitePlugin
4 --- argsArray$argument_0
```

I don't know if it's the function itself (openDatabase) that doesn't recognize the args, if I have to use another function or it's due to I didn't pre-populate the db by copying it to a specific folder.

react-native.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    dependency: {
        platforms: {
            ios: {
                project: './platforms/ios/SQLite.xcodeproj'
            },
            /* 
            // default config
            android: {
                sourceDir: './platforms/android'
            },
            */
            // changed
            android: {
                sourceDir:  "../node_modules/react-native-sqlite-storage/platforms/android-native",
                packageImportPath: "import io.liteglue.SQLitePluginPackage;",
                packageInstance: "new SQLitePluginPackage()"
            },
            windows: {
                sourceDir: './platforms/windows',
                solutionFile: 'SQLitePlugin.sln',
                projects: [
                  {
                    projectFile: 'SQLitePlugin/SQLitePlugin.vcxproj',
                    directDependency: true,
                  }
                ],
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this error also. For my case, it was just an operations sequence issue. This error occurred when I started the APP before installing the react-native-sqlite-storage package. When I restarted the APP, this error disappeared.

Examples for reference:
https://blog.logrocket.com/using-sqlite-with-react-native/
https://aboutreact.com/example-of-sqlite-database-in-react-native/